# How to get HTTP Status Code from AS3 NetStream Object?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

I'm trying to distinguish specifically between the 404 and 401 (or any) HTTP status codes, but the events raised by NetStream/NetConnect do not seem to include the HTTP status.

```
var url = "404_or_401_producing_url";

var _nc = new NetConnection(); 
_nc.connect(null);

var _ns = new NetStream(_nc);
_ns.play(url);
```

Is there an event or property available during this flow that includes the HTTP status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetConnection`/`NetStatus` doesn't work that way. It's meant to connect to RTMP servers, which don't throw 4xx status codes. You can, however, create an event listener.

```
connection = new NetConnection();
connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
    switch (event.info.code) {
        case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
            connectStream();
        break;
        case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
             trace("Stream not found: " + videoURL);
        break;
     }
 }
```

There are [a whole bunch of status codes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) to listen to, but none of them are 4xx errors

Answer (score 0):

To get HTTP status code, I recommand you to use `URLStream` instead of `NetStream` which dont use a `HTTPStatusEvent`.
For more details, take a look here (links from adobe) : [URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) and [HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html). And after verify the HTTP status, you can use or not `NetStream` to play your stream.